# Difference between Intel x86 version of Android and Android-x86

Tags: android, android-x86

I see that there are [Intel x86 version of Android](https://01.org/android-IA) and [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) initiatives. As far as I understand, the latter is a full-fledged effort that's entirely open sourced. Not sure about the former. Is there any difference between them at all? How much of them is common?

Thanks.

Comment: you may get an answer here but also consider android.stackexchange  though   you might have more luck with androidforums